# microsoft.visualstudio.telemetry error in xamarin visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I installed visual studio 2015 and xamarin
then i wnat open 'Strings.xml' but I saw this error
[image]

Please help me

Comment: I highly suggest you use Visual Studio 2019 instead of the very old 2015. Xamarin hasn't supported VS2015 for quite a while now. Just grab community edition, it is free.

Comment: what does happen if you remove it from references? Do you know how to add it from NuGet again, don't you?

Comment: i use from nuget but i saw this error Install    Could not install package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry 16.3.59'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry -Version 16.3.59
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: I strongly recommend you to install vs 2019 too , vs 2015 is outdated .